# How do you get form property when input has same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with form and asking for the `target` attribute - expecting in the following example it would be `_blank`.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get" target="_blank">
    First name: <input type="text" name="target"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="accessKey" value="somwhere" class="">
</form>
```

Instead the `form.target` is a reference to the `input` with name `target`.

This is visible in the chrome debugger, but other named items like `lname` above don't appear, `form.lname` does give the `lname` input however.

Is there some way to get `form.target` property and not the forms element named target? Or is it necessary to go to the `form.attributes` to get the source value?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `form` is a variable holding a reference to the `<form />` element, you can use the `getAttribute()` method:

```
var target = form.getAttribute('target');
```

Or the jQuery equivalents, `attr()`:

```
var target = $(form).attr('target');
```

Or `prop()` (which is preferred where possible):

```
var target = $(form).prop('target');
```

Comment: The jQuery equivalent is `.attr()`, not `.prop()`.

Comment: True. Although if following best practices you should use prop() where possible. Updated to note.

Comment: `.prop(prop)` and `.attr(attr)` are just accessors/mutators for `form[prop]` and `form.getAttribute(attr)` respectively. They serve different purposes because they are different tools. Saying you should prefer one over the other is like saying you should prefer a claw hammer over a ball peen hammer: it will depend entirely on context.

Comment: It was my understanding `.attr` represented more often attributes from the source document, where as `.prop` is the active document with potential modifications after loading.  Also attribute being from doc are strings, where as properties may be converted to a native representation bool/int or other objects.

Comment: `$(form).prop('target');` gets the `object for input[name="target"]` and not the expected string "_blank".  
As a work around so far I would test the prop for `typeof ===object` and then get the attribute instead, but seems a hack to do so.